# C# Help Using Multiple Forms

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I am trying to create a application with multiple forms,

I have placed the forms on top of each other in the section needed.

However, the code as provided does not work.

```
    private void home_butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Home_Panel.Visible = true;
        Home_Panel.BringToFront();
    }

    private void Intro_butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Introduction.Visible = true;
        Introduction.BringToFront();
        Home_Panel.Visible = false;
        Crime.Visible = false;
    }

    private void Crime_butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Crime.Visible = true;
        Crime.BringToFront();
        Home_Panel.Visible = false;
        Introduction.Visible = false;
    }
```

It will the home_Panel on start up but when you click on a button it will only show the Crimes Panel.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are `Home_Panel`, `Introduction`, `Crime` form classes ? How are you using them? When are you initializing them?

Comment: They are User Controls which are created then copied and pasted to the main Form for use.

Comment: can you show us the code where they are being declared and initialized?

Comment: i ont understand what you mean, they are created in a separate user control then copied and pasted to my GUI, the forms contain no code just text. Its weird how it shows the 1 panel after selecting the correct button but not the rest

Comment: Are you using this for example? `IntroductionForm Introduction = new IntroductionForm()` ? Declared and initialized?

Comment: Well i wouldnt need to would i because the form is placed for instance on the main form so they are all on top of eachother and i only want each one to show for the relevent button

Comment: @WilliamShakespeare - What do you mean by "copied and pasted to the main Form"?

Comment: @WilliamShakespeare - Can you also clarify if you are using multiple forms or multiple user controls?

Comment: @Enigmativity Multiple User Controls

Comment: @WilliamShakespeare - Can you please show the code where the User Controls are created and added to your form?

Comment: @Enigmativity There is no code they are created on Visual Studio under prjoect - add user control. i then add the labels etc i want than copy and paste it onto form 1.

Comment: @WilliamShakespeare - Look at the code behind file that Visual Studio creates - it's all valid C# and it shows exactly what is being created and where.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `show` and `hide` methods for forms instead of bringing them to the front and setting the visibility? E.G.

```
private void home_butt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Home_Panel.Show();
    Crime.Hide();
    Introduction.Hide();
}
```

And vice versa for the other button events?

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't work for some reason it will only show the 1 panel. not the rest

Comment: Have you created instances of each form in which to show and hide? I note in your other comments that you say you created them in Visual Studio and added labels, but does an instance of the form objects exist in the scope of the button click event handlers?